# Spring Security - Wrong CSRF Token in Response After Authentication

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, csrf-token

My understanding of Spring Security is that, when authenticating, a csrf token is generated before the authentication is performed, and another is generated after the authentication is successfully completed.

I've noticed that the wrong csrf token is returned in the response header after authentication, which then leads to 403 responses (Invalid CSRF token) when attempting to hit POST endpoints. The project can be found on github; [here](https://github.com/UserProgrammer/template-rest-api). Here is some of the security-specific code:

Spring security configuration:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();

    httpSecurity
        .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
        //.antMatchers("/status").permitAll().and()
        .cors().and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository).and()
        .authenticationProvider(new BasicAuthenticationProvider())
        .addFilterAfter(new CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter(csrfTokenRepository), CsrfFilter.class)
        .addFilterBefore(new CustomBasicAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
  }

  @Bean
  CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();

    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(new ArrayList<>());
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(ImmutableList.of("GET", "POST"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(ImmutableList.of("*"));
    configuration.setExposedHeaders(ImmutableList.of("X-Csrf-Token"));

    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);

    return source;
  }
}
```

Filter for adding CSRF token in response header:

```
public class CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
  private static final String CSRF_TOKEN_NAME = "x-csrf-token";
  private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository;

  public CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter(CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository) {
    this.csrfTokenRepository = csrfTokenRepository;
  }

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.addHeader(CSRF_TOKEN_NAME, csrfTokenRepository.loadToken(request).getToken());

    System.out.println("shoop: " + csrfTokenRepository.loadToken(request).getToken());
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    System.out.println("shap: " + csrfTokenRepository.loadToken(request).getToken());
  }
}
```

Filter for basic authentication:

```
public class CustomBasicAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    BasicAuthenticationToken basicAuthenticationToken = generateBasicAuthenticationToken(request);

    if (basicAuthenticationToken != null) {
      SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(basicAuthenticationToken);
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
  }

  private BasicAuthenticationToken generateBasicAuthenticationToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println("generateBasicAuthenticationToken");
    String authorizationHeaderValue = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    BasicAuthenticationToken basicAuthenticationToken = null;

    if (authorizationHeaderValue != null && authorizationHeaderValue.startsWith("Basic ")) {
      System.out.println("basic authentication header provided");
      final String base64EncodedCredentials = authorizationHeaderValue.replace("Basic ", "").trim();
      final byte[] decodedCredentials = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64EncodedCredentials);
      final String credentials = new String(decodedCredentials);
      final String[] splitCredentials = credentials.split(":", 2);

      System.out.println("credentials: " + credentials);
      System.out.println("username: " + splitCredentials[0]);
      System.out.println("password: " + splitCredentials[1]);

      basicAuthenticationToken = new BasicAuthenticationToken (splitCredentials[0], splitCredentials[1]);
    }

    return basicAuthenticationToken;
  }
}
```

Basic authentication provider:

```
public class BasicAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
  private final String VALID_USERNAME = "user";
  private final String VALID_PASSWORD = "pass";

  @Override
  public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    System.out.println("BasicAuthenticationProvider");
    String username = authentication.getName();
    String password = (String) authentication.getCredentials();

    if (!username.equals(VALID_USERNAME) || !password.equals(VALID_PASSWORD)) {
      throw new InvalidCredentialsException("Invalid credentials provided.");
    }

    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, "", Collections.emptyList());
  }

  @Override
  public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
    return BasicAuthenticationToken.class.equals(aClass);
  }
}
```

To confirm that the issue has to do with an invalid csrf token, I printed out the csrf tokens generated by spring before and after authentication, and compared those tokens against the token in the response header. Also, when I run the app with debug-level logging, I get the following error message from spring when trying to hit an authenticated POST endpoint after I've authenticated: `Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:8080/auth/status`

I used the following curl commands when performing this test:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:8080/login' -H 'Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNz' -v
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:8080/auth/status' -H 'Cookie: <session id>' -H 'x-csrf-token: <csrf token>' -v
```

P.S.: For anyone running the project I linked to above locally, when you run script/build you will be asked for your credentials on your local machine. This is because I'm using docker on a linux machine, which requires superuser privileges.